# Rails Relations

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, database-relations

I've 3 tables:

```
profiles, users, payment_details
```

Now, in `models/user.rb` I've the following:

```
has_one :profile, :dependent => :destroy
has_one :payment_detail, :dependent => :destroy
```

In `models/profile.rb` I have:

```
has_one :payment_detail, :through => :user
```

And in `models/payment_details.rb` I have:

```
has_one :profile, :through => :user
```

Then I have a `:profile` form with a `:payment_details` nested form.

For some reason the `:payment_details` gets the `:user_id` updated with the `:id` from `:profiles` instead of the `:user_id` from `:profiles`

Comment: You seem to be missing the `belongs_to` side of each relation. Is that just a copy-paste omission?

Comment: Yes, I have `belongs_to :user` in both `payment_detail` and `profile` models.

Comment: Give us the view with the form and the controller.

Answer (score 1):

Based on the documentation, the behavior of `accepts_nested_attributes_for` doesn't seem to be well-defined for `:through` associations. The relationship is generally assumed to be direct parent-child, so it's not surprising that you would see odd behavior like this.

You should either handle the form through the `User` model, accepting attributes for the `PaymentDetail` model, or combine your models in some way. I rarely find it useful to use `has_one` associations, because the cost of maintaining them tend to outweigh benefits, but it always depends on your use case. If you don't have too many columns, you might want to combine `User` with `Profile`, and maybe with `PaymentDetail` to simplify your code.

Comment: I'll try a different way. Instead of having the nested routes I am gonna save the `PaymentDetail` directly on the `Profile` controller. I tried to vote in your answer but I don't have enough reputation, sorry.